# Not getting data in xml parsing properly

Tags: android, xml-parsing

Here I have no data, Then I got Pcode 0, but here i could not get Pcode 0, My intention is getting Pcode zero and display **"Not Data Here"** Message.
I have using data parsing with xml, but could not properly, I have error with parsing error, but could not get find, where i am doing error. Here is the my code:

```
 Log.d("user id is ", userId + "!");                

 String input = String.format("<Es_Request><Data><UserId>%s</UserId></Data></Es_Request>",  userId);
 String response = HttpPostRetreiver .retriver(Url.url_getting_assignment,                                      input, GradeAssignmentActivity.this);
        if (response != null) {
    esResponse = XmlParser.parseAssignmentProfessorResponse(response);
        Log.d("TAG", "Checking Value="+ esResponse.getResponseCode().getpCode());
        if (esResponse.getResponseCode().getpCode().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
        assignmentDataInfo = esResponse .getAssignmentListData().getAssignmentDataInfo();
        int size = assignmentDataInfo.size();
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < size; i++) {
                EduInterface.assignmetIdArrayList.add(assignmentDataInfo.get(i).getAssignmentId());
                EduInterface.assignmetNameArrayList.add(assignmentDataInfo.get(i).getAssignmentName());
      }
    } else {

       test = 1;
       Log.d("else", "Not data Here");
  }
    }

  } else {
    Log.d("TAG", "Error in Webservice");

    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Grade Assignment class", e.toString() + "");
 }
```

I Have got,First user id is 5 ! then got error  Grade Assignemt Class error. I have been problem parsing Here is the pasing>

**Input String:**    `Es_Request><Data><UserId>913</UserId></Data></Es_Request>`

**Response String :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Es_Response><Es_Session_Id></Es_Session_Id>
 <Bpn_Request_Id></Bpn_Request_Id><Response_Code><Pcode>0</Pcode><Scode>Unsuccessful</Scode></Response_Code><Data><message>Assignments not found for Professor & CourseId.</message></Data></Es_Response>
```

Here is the my handler class:

```
@Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        content = new StringBuilder();
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Data")) {
            assignmentListData=new AssignmentListData();
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("assignments")) {
            assignmentItems = new AssignmentItems();
        }
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Es_Response")) {
            esResponse=new EsResponse();
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Response_Code")) {
            responseCode=new ResponseCode();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
         if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Pcode")) {
              responseCode.setpCode(content.toString());
              Log.d("TAG", "Pcode Value->"+content.toString());
            }
          else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Response_Code")) {
              esResponse.setResponseCode(responseCode);
            }
          else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("AssignmentId")) {
              assignmentItems.setAssignmentId(content.toString());
            }
          else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("AssignmentName")) {
              assignmentItems.setAssignmentName(content.toString());
            }

          else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Assignments")) {
              assignmentDataInfo.add(assignmentItems);
            }
          else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Data")) {
              assignmentListData.setAssignmentDataInfo(assignmentDataInfo);
            }
          else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Es_Response")) {
                esResponse.setAssignmentListData(assignmentListData);
            }

    }
```

I got logcat this:

```
04-30 19:25:51.378: D/getting course list->(1598): Line 322---RESPONSE<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Es_Response><Es_Session_Id></Es_Session_Id>
04-30 19:25:51.378: D/getting course list->(1598): <Bpn_Request_Id></Bpn_Request_Id><userIDName>913</userIDName><schoolID>1</schoolID><CourseID>977</CourseID><Response_Code><Pcode>0</Pcode><Scode>Unsuccessful</Scode><Test>977</Test><ROLE ID>4</ROLE ID></Response_Code><Data><message>Assignments not found for Professor & CourseId.</message></Data></Es_Response>
04-30 19:25:51.378: D/user id is(1598): 913
04-30 19:25:51.378: D/school id is(1598): 1
04-30 19:25:51.388: D/TAG(1598): Pcode Value->0
04-30 19:25:51.398: W/System.err(1598): org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 2, column 189: not well-formed (invalid token)
04-30 19:25:51.398: W/System.err(1598):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:499)
04-30 19:25:51.398: W/System.err(1598):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:484)
04-30 19:25:51.409: W/System.err(1598):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:309)
04-30 19:25:51.409: W/System.err(1598):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:267)
04-30 19:25:51.409: W/System.err(1598):     at sdei.edustatusnew.services.XmlParser.parseAssignmentProfessorResponse(XmlParser.java:840)
04-30 19:25:51.409: W/System.err(1598):     at sdei.edustatusnew.gradebook.GradeAssignmentActivity$GetDataTask.doInBackground(GradeAssignmentActivity.java:326)
04-30 19:25:51.409: W/System.err(1598):     at sdei.edustatusnew.gradebook.GradeAssignmentActivity$GetDataTask.doInBackground(GradeAssignmentActivity.java:1)
04-30 19:25:51.427: W/Trace(1598): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-30 19:25:51.427: W/Trace(1598): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-30 19:25:51.438: W/Trace(1598): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-30 19:25:51.438: W/Trace(1598): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-30 19:25:51.468: W/System.err(1598):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-30 19:25:51.478: W/System.err(1598):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-30 19:25:51.478: W/System.err(1598):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-30 19:25:51.488: W/System.err(1598):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-30 19:25:51.488: W/System.err(1598):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-30 19:25:51.488: W/System.err(1598):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-30 19:25:51.488: E/Grade Assignment class(1598): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Would you please help, What is the error on my code. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Please use the version of `Log.e` that prints a stack trace: `Log.e("Grade Assignment class", "parse failed", e);`. By just printing `e.toString() + ""`, your logcat output is missing vital information needed to track down what's happening. All we see is "java.lang.NullPointerException".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you have been problem in **Assignments not found for Professor & CourseId.** tag in response string. Please try **&-> and** you may solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You have a error in your XML. It is crystal clear in your logcat stacktrace i.e., `org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 2, column 189: not well-formed (invalid token)`

The tag at line 2 column 189 is `<ROLE ID>4</ROLE ID>`. The XML tag should not contain any white space characters.

**The solution is change it to `<ROLE_ID>4</ROLE_ID>`**